# how to inherit the value of the variable in my first frame to the other variable of my second frame in java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){  
  if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "PROCEED TO NEXT LEVEL?", "AWESOME!!! CORRECT ANSWER ---",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
     String myCoin = coin.getText();
   int   points = Integer.parseInt(myCoin);


new hint().points2 = pointq1;
    new hint().setVisible(true);
    }
```

}
This is the code of my first frame, and i have a value of my coin button in my first frame, so i am getting the value of my coin button and convert it to int and put the value in 'points' variable , hint() is my second frame and 'points2' is my variable in second frame. Now, I just want my points2 variable will be equal to he value of my coins button that is placed in variable 'points'.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0):

Create/Update your class hint to have a variable in its constructor like so:

```
class Hint{
    private int points2;
    public Hint(int points2){
        this.points2 = points2;
    }
}
```

So, in your new implementations, it would be like:

```
String myCoin = coin.getText(); 
int points1 = Integer.parseInt(myCoin);
new Hint(points1).setVisible(true);
```